# Is this is phishing attempt?

Tags: email, phishing

I received an email, purporting to be from Microsoft Account as a Security Alert. The address looks legit (account-security-noreply@accountprotection.microsoft.com) but the problem is, the email address they refer to in the body of the email is not a Microsoft address. As a matter of fact, it's an @mac.com address. Everything I have seen in the community seems to indicate the email is legit, but why would I get a security alert from Microsoft for an @mac account? And if, as I suspect, it isn't legit, how do I report the email? I have already blocked the sender, and I haven't clicked on anything in the body of the email.

Answer (score 2):

> Everything I have seen in the community seems to indicate the email is legit, but why would I get a security alert from Microsoft for an @mac account?

You can sign up to Microsoft services using whatever e-mail address you want. They can provide information in connection with this.

The best test for phishing is to check where links leads to. If they lead to for instance aka.ms or microsoft.com it's probably not phishing. If you're in doubt - don't follow any links. Go to whatever service the mail is indicating, and check for alerts there. Do not use the links in the email, but write the *correct* address in your browser yourself.

Before entering any information in a web page based on links in e-mail, double check that it's the expected address for that site or service.

> And if, as I suspect, it isn't legit, how do I report the email? I have already blocked the sender, and I haven't clicked on anything in the body of the email.

Delete & forget. Phishing attemts are way too common to react to. I'm averaging a few hundred a day to my primary e-mail address.